# org.jetbrains.annotations @NotNull interfare with Mockito when mock a private method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, annotations, powermock

I'm trying to mock a private method of my service with powermock by passing it the mockito matcher "eq" for its arguments. One of those argument is annotated with the @NotNull decorator from jetbrains.

When I run the test, I get the following error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter X of Y must not be null**

Target for testing

```java
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
...

class Service {
...
  private Map<String, Object> computeDataModel(User user, @NotNull Configuration configuration, Object providedDataModel) {...
}
```

Test Class

```java
PowerMockito.when(service, "computeDataModel", eq(user), eq(configuration), eq(providedDataModel)).thenReturn(dataModel);
```

I also tried with any(Configuration.class) but without success.

Do you know how to process ?
Thank you for your attention

Comment: `eq`, `any` and all other argument matchers always return `null`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerMockito is calling real method instead of mocked private one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42018713/powermockito-is-calling-real-method-instead-of-mocked-private-one)

Comment: You could try the `PowerMockito.doReturn(…).when(…)` form instead of `when(…).thenReturn(…)`.

Comment: Thanks @knittl 
that's work for me with PowerMockito.doReturn(…).when(…)

Comment: I just need to add @Spy on my service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the annotation really, but with calling the real method with null values.

```
PowerMockito.when(service, "computeDataModel", eq(user), eq(configuration), eq(providedDataModel))
    .thenReturn(dataModel);
```

calls the real method.

`eq` is a matcher and returns `null`, effectively calling your method with 3 null arguments.

If you want to avoid calling your real method, you could use a different method of PowerMockito:

```
PowerMockito.doReturn(dataModel)
    .when(service, "computeDataModel", eq(user), eq(configuration), eq(providedDataModel));
```